# how can I change registry values at installation time with windows installer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-installer

I have created a deployment project using VS 2005. By default, files are installed in AppDataFolder. There are also 2 string values added to the registry during the installation. These registry values represent the path to some dll files found in the install dir.
When the user chooses the default installation directory everything works fine. But if the user choose another directory, instead of having the registry values with the user selected directory, I still get the default values.
How can I change that? Is it possible to do it during the deployment project creation?

Thanks,

Olivier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using the [AppDataFolder] property, I should have used [TARGETDIR]

Answer (score 0):

Use [reg.exe](http://commandwindows.com/reg.htm) from command line.

You could call that exe from your program and provide the correct parameters.

`reg.exe` is included since Windows XP.

Comment: Is reg.exe the only option? Preferably I'd like to do it programmatically.

Thanks,

Olivier.